# Nested nginx reverse proxies using Docker

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have linux VPS, with domain e.g. "example.com". There is multiple services served on the domain, so there should be some API gateway.

My configuration is:

- native nginx reverse proxy running on VPS, routing "example.com" domain inside `example-nginx` API gateway (container #1)
- example-nginx API gateway, e.g

  ```
  / => Vue.js project (container #2)
  /api => PHP service (container #3)
  /another => PHP service (container #4)
  ```
- and each container (containers #2, #3, #4) is running it's own nginx web server to serve it's contents (bcs. this is how the docker image is built so it is able to run independently on other services)

**But this is 3 nested nginx servers so I am wondering, if this can be considered best practice.** But also I have no idea if there is some better way, because as described, I need all the layers.

I can probably merge native nginx with api gateway, but if I do this, I will have to manually configure api gateway on each host where the app will be deployed. So this is probably not an option.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this is a problem?

Comment: @super thanks for comment. That's it. I don't. But I am more Dev than Ops person, so I just want to confirm with anyone who can handle this, if it is ok or not. E.g. some performance issues related to longer response time (#1 nginx->#2 nginx->#3 nginx - each takes some time and slow the request little bit) comes to my mind.

Comment: Have you read the [ingress controller](https://traefik.io/glossary/kubernetes-ingress-and-ingress-controller-101/) manual already ?

Comment: @VictorGubin Thanks for tip, I haven't. Since I am running on single node, I am not yet familiar with Kubernetes. Will look at it the manual, thanks.